# processing JSON data sent by php with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, sql, json

I've got a problem with the interaction between PHP and JavaScript via JSON.

The PHP-Script reads data from my database. The SQL result consists of 1 row.

name   | lat        | lng

---

Kilian | 45.1252335 | 32.2142380

It is encoded into JSON:

```
$query = "SELECT name, lat, lng FROM location l, user u WHERE u.email = l.email";
$result = mysqli_query ($dbc, $query) or die ('Error querying database.');
$to_encode = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $to_encode[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($to_encode);
```

The JavaScript program loads the JSON file from the php-script (get_locations.php):

```
$.getJSON('get_locations.php', function (data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, name) {
            alert(name.parent_level);
        });
    });
```

But there is no alert in the browser. If i inspect the sent JSON in Chrome it just says [].
How can i get to the sent name, lat and lng?

Edit: The real world output of get_locations.php is [].
Converting the JSON to string always resulted in [].

Comment: You are sure and have checked that the query has results? If so, try with pushing elements to `$to_enconde` using an index instead of [] (For some reason, json_encode does weird things with that).

Comment: Could you add some real world output from get_locations.php? In javascript `console.log(data)` could also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing functions:

```
$query = "SELECT name, lat, lng FROM location l, user u WHERE u.email = l.email";
$result = mysqli_query ($dbc, $query) or die ('Error querying database.');
$to_encode = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $to_encode[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($to_encode);
```

You create a `mysqli` query, so you should get the result with [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) rather than the `mysql_` version.

Comment: You are welcome!  Don't forget to click the check mark next to answers that get things working for you for future questions as well. ^^ (You also get rep for doing it and would make those helping you in the future more willing to do so.)